# AWS EC2 schedule python file with an AWS-Service like a cron job

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

I am new to AWS. I created an EC2 instance, installed a python environment and a connection to my GitHub repository. Now I try to schedule a .sh file, which executes my git-pull, python file, etc. A solution would be, just to use a cron-job (in the instance), but is there a solution from an AWS-service, where I have control and overview? To be clear, I don t like to schedule my Instance.

I am thankful for all help!

Comment: If everything you wish to do is "on the instance", then what you are doing sounds perfectly fine. If you have multiple servers, with actions triggered by external events, then something "external" would be required.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is overkill for you needs, but you asked if there is an AWS service that runs cronjobs on Ec2 Linux instances, and there is one called [opsworks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingcookbook-extend-cron.html) that does this.

> Although you can manually set up cron jobs on individual Linux-based instances by connecting to them with SSH, and editing their crontab entries, a key advantage of AWS OpsWorks Stacks is that you can direct it to run the task across an entire layer of instances.

It may be overkill though since you have one instance.

Comment: Thank you, i will have a closer look on it the next days and will accept if this helps me